# Hide BrightcoveVideoView Player controls?

Tags: android, brightcove

How can I hide the media controls of the brightcoveVideoView?

I haven't hook the media controller up at all.

But play,pause,scrub controls still show up.

I see no direct method on the brightcoveVideoView that hides the controls.

Comment: brightcoveVideoView.setMediaController((MediaController) null);                                                                                                                                                          
ref this : http://docs.brightcove.com/en/perform/mobile-sdks/brightcove-player-sdk-for-android/guides/player-controls.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out these answers, maybe something there will be of help. I am also trying to work this out at the moment.
- https://docs.brightcove.com/en/perform/mobile-sdks/brightcove-player-sdk-for-android/reference/current/javadoc/com/brightcove/player/mediacontroller/package-summary.html
https://gist.github.com/pajatopmr/e277cddf711a7b531116